# How to iterate through a nested dictionary and return the keys and values?

Tags: python

Say I have a nested dictionary like so:

```
dict = ["{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00001', 'fields': {'name': 'Valentino Solomon', 'latitude': 57.13514, 'longitude': -2.11731}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00002', 'fields': {'name': 'Luna Armstrong', 'latitude': 57.13875, 'longitude': -2.09089}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00003', 'fields': {'name': 'Jaylen Crane', 'latitude': 57.101, 'longitude': -2.1106}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00004', 'fields': {'name': 'Christopher Fritz', 'latitude': 57.10801, 'longitude': -2.23776}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00005', 'fields': {'name': 'Timothy Hutchinson', 'latitude': 57.10076, 'longitude': -2.27073}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00006', 'fields': {'name': 'Yesenia Reeves', 'latitude': 57.13868, 'longitude': -2.16525}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00007', 'fields': {'name': 'Cameron Vargas', 'latitude': 57.16115, 'longitude': -2.15543}}"]
```

How can I iterate through this to get the fields `pk` and the keys and values inside the key `fields` so that the return is:

```
data = "{'pk': 'C00001', 'name': 'Valentino Solomon', 'latitude': 57.13514, 'longitude': -2.11731}",
"{'pk': 'C00002', 'name': 'Luna Armstrong', 'latitude': 57.13875, 'longitude': -2.09089}",
"{'pk': 'C00003', 'name': 'Jaylen Crane', 'latitude': 57.101, 'longitude': -2.1106}",
"{'pk': 'C00004', 'name': 'Christopher Fritz', 'latitude': 57.10801, 'longitude': -2.23776}",
"{'pk': 'C00005', 'name': 'Timothy Hutchinson', 'latitude': 57.10076, 'longitude': -2.27073}"
```

Thanks!

I can access the fields by using this:

```
print(customers[0]['fields'])
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: I've been trying all day bro :/ I'll paste code that i've tried

Comment: Is the dict wrong?

Comment: hmm what do you mean wrong? I used ```customers = serializers.serialize("python",Customer.objects.all())``` django query and outputted it into a csv file

Comment: I felt it should be list of dicts `[{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00001', 'fields': {'name': 'Valentino Solomon', 'latitude': 57.13514, 'longitude': -2.11731}}...]` else it is just a string which is returned.

Comment: May be this already gives you a list Customer.objects.all() however not deserialised as json. So you could iterate over that and generate what ever you need from it.

Comment: ah yes you're right i'm missing [], I just used what was pasted in the csv file but if i use print(customers) then it includes the ```[]```

Comment: wouldnt ```Customer.objects.all() ``` give me a model instance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244696/discussion-between-coldy-and-redrum).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert that dict into a list and make every entry a dict. Then just iterate through the list, put it in a dict and access it like you would every other dict.

```
list: list = [{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00001', 'fields': {'name': 'Valentino Solomon', 'latitude': 57.13514, 'longitude': -2.11731}}, 
{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00002', 'fields': {'name': 'Luna Armstrong', 'latitude': 57.13875, 'longitude': -2.09089}}, 
{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00003', 'fields': {'name': 'Jaylen Crane', 'latitude': 57.101, 'longitude': -2.1106}}, 
{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00004', 'fields': {'name': 'Christopher Fritz', 'latitude': 57.10801, 'longitude': -2.23776}}, 
{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00005', 'fields': {'name': 'Timothy Hutchinson', 'latitude': 57.10076, 'longitude': -2.27073}}, 
{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00006', 'fields': {'name': 'Yesenia Reeves', 'latitude': 57.13868, 'longitude': -2.16525}}, 
{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00007', 'fields': {'name': 'Cameron Vargas', 'latitude': 57.16115, 'longitude': -2.15543}}]

for entry in list:
    dict: dict = entry
    print(dict['pk'])
    print(dict['fields']['name'])
```

If anybody has a similar list like OP, where all the dicts are in one single string (convert string of dicts without commas into list of dicts), you can use this bit of code:
import ast

```
def convertToList(inString: str):
    i: int = 0
    closeCounter: int = 0
    openCounter: int = 0
    firstOpen: int = 0
    outList: list = []
    while i < len(inString):
        openPos = inString.find("{", i)
        closePos = inString.find("}", i)
        if closePos == -1:
            return outList
        if openPos < closePos and openPos != -1:
            openCounter += 1
            if openCounter == 1:
                firstOpen = i
            i = openPos + 1
        elif closePos < openPos or openPos == -1:
            closeCounter += 1
            if openCounter == closeCounter:
                dict: dict = ast.literal_eval(inString[firstOpen:closePos+1])
                outList.append(dict)
                openCounter = 0
                closeCounter = 0
            i = closePos + 1
    return outList

                

list: list = ["{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00001', 'fields': {'name': 'Valentino Solomon', 'latitude': 57.13514, 'longitude': -2.11731}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00002', 'fields': {'name': 'Luna Armstrong', 'latitude': 57.13875, 'longitude': -2.09089}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00003', 'fields': {'name': 'Jaylen Crane', 'latitude': 57.101, 'longitude': -2.1106}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00004', 'fields': {'name': 'Christopher Fritz', 'latitude': 57.10801, 'longitude': -2.23776}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00005', 'fields': {'name': 'Timothy Hutchinson', 'latitude': 57.10076, 'longitude': -2.27073}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00006', 'fields': {'name': 'Yesenia Reeves', 'latitude': 57.13868, 'longitude': -2.16525}}" 
"{'model': 'network.customer', 'pk': 'C00007', 'fields': {'name': 'Cameron Vargas', 'latitude': 57.16115, 'longitude': -2.15543}}"]

list0 = convertToList(list[0])
print(list0)
for entry in list0:
    dict: dict = entry
    print(dict['pk'])
    print(dict['fields']['name'])
```

Comment: thank you for this! how did you convert my ```dict``` to your ```list```? because my dict has " "  between the each element :/  I tried this ``` list: list = dict
print(list)``` but it still contains the " " unlike yours which doesn't

Comment: I literally just removed the double quotes (") and added commas by hand lol. Where do you get that data from or more important how do you get that data passed?

Comment: Oh  I got it from a Django model using the following query set: customers = serializers.serialize("python",Customer.objects.all()) this gave me the data in the format shown in my original post and the data is loooong so I can’t do that by hand lol

Comment: Are you sure there are no commas between the single lines? Otherwise this is just one string. Anyways maybe you should try the function model_to_dict from Django, since it is quite hard to translate that result into even a list. I could probably write a function, but that function would need to look for every { & } to determine where the next entry is.

Comment: i'm going to triple check but the output SHOULD have commas so maybe i was looking at a different terminal? idk but your solution would work for a normal dictionary with commas so thats good enough for me.. there has to be something wrong with my code or how i'm extracting the data lol

Comment: if the output has commas, you can just convert those strings using ast.literal_eval from ast. But if you do happen to need the function, I actually am currently working on one that converts such a string like you pasted into a list like I made by hand lol

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244703/discussion-between-jonii-and-redrum).